# Drupal 7 db_update - checking for errors

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have a custom Drupal 7 module with an 'edit' page.

The form fields reference a couple of database tables, so to process the form, we attempt to update the first table, and we try to set a '$error' to 'true' and check against $error before we attempt to update the next table. For example:

HTML:

```
<input name="field1" />
<input name="field2" />
```

PHP:

```
$error = false;

$update_table_1 = db_update('table1')
    ->fields(array(
        'field1' => $_POST['field1'],
    ))
    ->condition('id', $id)
    ->execute();

if(!update_table_1) {
    $error = true;
}

if(!$error) {
    $update_table_2 = db_update('table2')
        ->fields(array(
            'field2' => $_POST['field2'],
        ))
        ->condition('id', $id)
        ->execute();

    if(!$update_table_2) {
        $error = true;
    }
}
```

**Problem:** If only updating something in table 2, it will throw an error before it event gets to update table 2 because db_query says that it is not true since the field was the same as what was in the database (no change). Really, I only want to stop it if there was a database / code error.

Does the Drupal 7 db_update API have some kind of error reporting function like mysql_error()? Other suggestions?

Comment: FYI, you might get more specific answers at http://drupal.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The safest way you can do it is with a transaction and proper PHP error checking:

```
$transaction = db_transaction();

try {
  // Query 1
  db_update(...);

  // Query 2
  db_update(...);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  // Rollback the transaction
  $transaction->rollback();

  // Do something with the exception (inform user, etc)
}
```

I should mention the transaction is only necessary if you don't want the changes from the *first* query to persist if the *second* query fails. It's quite a common requirement but might not fit your use case.

Comment: I tried this, and this is exactly what I needed - the try / catch exception. But I would like to take it a step forward as you have with the db_transaction()->rollback. Does this work with Drupal's db_update? Perhaps I have not implemented it correctly.

Comment: It is absolutely necessary in reverse: I don't want for the second query to persist if the first fails, and so I set my $error variable to true, and it works great. But ideally, let each query fail if one does.

Comment: That will be handled by the `try...catch`. If the first query fails, control will pass to the `catch` block and the second query will never be run. Adding the transaction will rollback all queries that were performed within the `try` block, if any of them fail

Comment: I placed '$transaction = db_transaction();' at the top of the script before anything happens. Within each 'catch(), I placed '$transaction->rollback();'. But it still keeps changes to the first db_update query when the second one fails.

Comment: Oh. So there needs to be ONE try / catch with all of the queries inside of it?

Comment: That's the normal way yes, [the docs](http://drupal.org/node/355875) explain it better than I can

Comment: I looked through the docs, but I don't know what I am doing wrong. It commits the changes to the first db_update query even thought the second one fails.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28846/discussion-between-nitsuj-and-clive)

Comment: @Clive and here master clive . you are awesome ;)